# Left indent for figure with program

Tags: floats, indentation, program

In my document, I have some pseudocode sections created using the `program` environment (tried several alternatives, but liked that one most, so I want to stick to that). Now I would simply like to indent the pseudocode sections on the left by some millimeters to make it more stand out from the body text, as depicted here:

[image: IndentProgram]

Is there some simple way to achieve that (globally, if possible)?

MWE for the given example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{program}
        \BEGIN
        a=a+1;
        \END
    \end{program}
    \caption{Example code}
    \label{alg:exampleCode}
\end{figure}

 \lipsum[25]
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patch `program` so that it thinks to be in a list environment indented by the amount you prefer.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pretocmd{\program}{\list{}{\leftmargin3em}\item\relax}{}{}% <---- change 3em to suit
\apptocmd{\endprogram}{\endlist}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{program}
  \BEGIN
  a=a+1;
  \END
\end{program}

\caption{Example code}
\label{alg:exampleCode}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[25]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You should contact the package author: the code is replete with `\sf`, `\rm` and `\bf` commands that have been obsolete for twenty years. With `scrbook` you get warnings that the commands may be removed from the class in a near future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `program` environment cannot be placed into a `\hbox` and so it can never be "centered" except by hand.  However, by placing it into a `\vbox`, it can be indented by a fixed amount (here 2in), if that solution is sufficient for your need.

The `\makebox[0pt][l]{}` is only to avoid an overfull box, lest the `\vbox` protrudes out the right margin.

This solution will not page break, but already being inside a figure float. that should not be an issue.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\setbox0=\vbox{%
    \begin{program}
        \BEGIN
        a=a+1;
        \END
    \end{program}
}\hspace{2in}\makebox[0pt][l]{\box0}
    \caption{Example code}
    \label{alg:exampleCode}
\end{figure}

 \lipsum[25]
 \end{document}
```

[image]